# Get line number from byte offset

Tags: text-processing, utilities

Having byte offset for a file.

Is there a tool that gives line number for this byte?

- Byte count starting with zero, as in: first byte is 0 not 1.
- Line number starting with 1.
- File can have both plain text, "binary" blobs, multibyte characters etc. But the section I am interested in: End of file, has only ASCII.

Example, file:

```
001
002
003  <<-- first zero on this line is byte 8
004
```

Having byte offset `8` that would give me line `3`.

Guess I could use something like this to find line number:

a. `tail -c+(offset + 1) file | wc -l`, here `+1` as `tail` counts from 1.
 b. `wc -l file`
 c. Then `tail -n+num`  where `num` is `a - b + 1`

But ... is there a, fairly common, tool that can give me `num` directly?

---

Edit, err: or the more obvious:

```
head -c+offset file | wc -l
```

Comment: Binary files don't have lines.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Lines in this context is data separated by `0x0a` bytes.

Comment: Probably not what you're asking, but Vim has a function for it.  It counts offsets from 1, so: `:echo byte2line(offset+1)`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Yes, and thanks. Tried with vim first. But even with `vim -b` and `vim` + `set binary` + open file it got corrupted. (Ah. Suddenly I recall which plugin messes it up). But, anyway, as I use this in batches and in combination with a range of scripts Vim was early abandoned. But +1 anyways.

Comment: @user367890 A binary file can have `0xa` anywhere. The concept of lines in a binary file is meaningless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your example,

```
001
002
003
004
```

byte number 8 is the second newline, not the `0` on the next line.

The following will give you the number of full lines after `$b` bytes:

```
$ dd if=data.in bs=1 count="$b" | wc -l
```

It will report `2` with `b` set to 8 and it will report `1` with `b` set to 7.

The `dd` utility, the way it's used here, will read from the file `data.in`, and will read `$b` blocks of size 1 byte.

As "icarus" rightly points out in the comments below, using `bs=1` is inefficient.  It's more efficient, in this particular case, to swap `bs` and `count`:

```
$ dd if=data.in bs="$b" count=1 | wc -l
```

This will have the same effect as the first `dd` command, but will read only one block of `$b` bytes.

The `wc` utility counts newlines, and a "line" in Unix is always terminated by a newline. So the above command will still say `2` if you set `b` to anything lower than 12 (the following newline). The result you are looking for is therefore whatever number the above pipeline reports, plus 1.

This will obviously also count the random newlines in the binary blob part of your file that precedes the ASCII text. If you knew where the ASCII bit starts, you could add `skip="$offset"` to the `dd` command, where `$offset` is the number of bytes to skip into the file.

Comment: @don_crissti `head: unknown option -- c`

Comment: @Kusalananda  You're using BSD head, options there are different

Comment: @Serg :-) I'm well aware of that. We don't know what tho OP uses, so I'm sticking to POSIX.

Comment: As I mentioned in Q: byte count starts with 0, not 1, therefore 8==0 ...

Comment: @user367890 In that case, use `$(( b - 1 ))`.

Comment: Thanks for edit: but not necessary nor desirable as I need the line number as is. With blobs and all. The third bulletpoint with information about blobs etc. was added after a comment in chat. I omitted it initially as I did not want to make it more complex or confusing then necessary. But now the damage is done I guess :)

Comment: @user367890 Reading files a byte at a time is VERY wasteful. Much better to set the `count` to 1 and the block size to the number of bytes, unless you are looking at very big files. At the very least you should only set ibs so you are not writing data a byte at a time to the pipe.

Comment: @icarus Incorporated bits of this into the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no dedicated tool like that, although it can be done fairly easily in python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

offset = int(sys.argv[2])
newline = 1
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    fd.seek(offset)
    while True:
        try:
            byte = fd.read(1)
            if byte == '\n': newline+=1
            #print(byte)
            offset = offset - 1
            fd.seek(offset)
        except ValueError:
            break
print(newline)
```

Usage is simple:

```
line4byte.py <FILE> <BYTE>
```

Test run:

```
$ cat input.txt
001
002
003
004
$ chmod +x ./line4byte.py                                                     
$ ./line4byte.py input.txt 8                                                  
3
```

This is a very quick and simple script. It doesn't check if the file is empty or not, so it works only on non-empty files.

Answer (score 4):

Track the bytes seen and emit the current line number should the given offset be within the sum:

```
perl -E '$off=shift;while(<>){$sum+=length;if($sum>=$off){say $.;exit}}' 8 file
```

Or at length:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
die "Usage: $0 offset file|-\n" if @ARGV != 2;
my $offset = shift;
shift if $ARGV[0] eq '-';
my $sum;
while (readline) {
    $sum += length;
    if ($sum >= $offset) {
        print "$.\n";
        exit;
    }
}
exit 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$perl -0nE 'say substr($_,0,8)=~ y/\n//'  ex
2
```

- `perl -0nE exp` slurps the input into `$_` and executes exp
- `substr(string,0,8)`  selects the first 8 bytes
- `y/\n//` removes the `\n` and returns its number

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)